# Ensure value of @Input() extends a common interface?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to ensure that an object instance passed via `@Input()` extends from a common interface?

I currently have:

```
@Input()
associatedObject: IDocument | IOrganization;
```

but it would be nicer to have something like:

```
@Input()
associatedObject: <T extends ICommonInterface>;
```

so I don't have to add new types in the future, provided the instance passes the interface check.

Comment: `associatedObject: ICommonInterface`?

Comment: Oh Lord, is it really that easy? That's embarrassing.

Comment: Well, that works, but I'm also able to pass other types of objects in at runtime and it's not complaining.

Comment: Do you use AoT? IIRC type safety in templates was on the roadmap and I don't think it's there yet. But it is impossible to achieve it with JiT.

Comment: It will complain if you programmatically set the input with an incorrect type, in test code for example. But at runtime, types don't exist anymore. And even when using the AOT compiler, it doesn't seem that input binding is compiled to static code, so there is no type checking.

Comment: @estus I do use AOT in my final build. As long as I have at least some checking in tests I should be alright. Thank you everyone for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using the extended interface as the `@Input()` type, which is working well for now.

```
@Input()
associatedObject: ICommonInterface;
```

Comment: This will of course check that usage of `associatedObject` conforms to the `ICommonInterface` type in this component, but will not check that people invoking your template and passing `[associatedObject]="myObject"` are passing the right type of object.